# How to remove special characters, spaces and trim in one string a character variable in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a little problem in R with a variable that is character type. My variable in data frame has a structure like this:

```
X1
ANGLO AUTOMOTRIZ S.A. MATRIZ
AUTOMOTORES Y ANEXOS / AYASA
ECUA - AUTO S.A. MATRIZ
METROCAR S.A. 10 DE AGOSTO
MOSUMI LA "Y"
```

My problem is I want a new variable without `./-""` and the strings must be grouped in one without spaces like this:

```
X2
ANGLOAUTOMOTRIZSAMATRIZ
AUTOMOTORESYANEXOSAYASA
ECUAAUTOSAMATRIZ
METROCARSA10DEAGOSTO
MOSUMILAY
```

It is possible to make this in R. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try `gsub`...

```
gsub( "\\.|/|\\-|\"|\\s" , "" , df$X1 )
#[1] "ANGLOAUTOMOTRIZSAMATRIZ" "AUTOMOTORESYANEXOSAYASA" "ECUAAUTOSAMATRIZ"       
#[4] "METROCARSA10DEAGOSTO"    "MOSUMILAY"
```

- `\\.` - match a literal `.`
- `|` - OR separator
- `/` - match a `/` (no escaping needed)
- `\\-` - match a literal `-`
- `\"` - match a literal `"`
- `\\s` - match a whitespace

`gsub` is greedy so tries to match as many as it can, and it is also vectorised so you can just pass the whole column at once. The second argument is the replacement value, which in this case is `""`, which replaces all matched characters with nothing.

Comment: Thanks @SimonO101 and for tick in a letter like `á` how I should remove this!

Comment: @Duck that's a bit more difficult to answer and depends on exact encodings etc. Try this page for starters¬ http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: I also recommend `Unicode::as.u_char()` you can paste the characters you are concerned with into that function and get the unicode encodings back which you can then put into your regex. I *think* this will be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Simpler: `gsub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]','',df$X1)`  .  The "^" character is your best friend!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft good point but if we're going down that route then maybe even `gsub('[[:punct:]]| ','',df$X1)`

Comment: @AnandaMahto - It sounds like Duck was asking how to remove the tick from the `á` (i.e. replacing it with `a`), rather than how to remove the character altogether...

Comment: Which is then *very* dependent on whether it is encoded as a single character or as two code points (i.e. a character followed by a combining mark). I suppose something like `gsub("\u0301|\u00E1" , "" , df$x , perl = TRUE )`

Comment: @Duck Ananda has done even better - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/11651712#11651712

Answer (score 6):

Since you are also dealing with accented characters, I can think of two options:

1. Get rid of the accented characters entirely.
2. Use `iconv` to attempt to "transliterate" the accented characters to ASCII characters.

Here are both. For both examples, I'm using the following sample text:

```
Z <- c("ANGLO AUTOMOTRIZ S.A. MATRIZ", "AUTOMOTORES Y ANEXOS / AYASA",
"ECUA - AUTO S.A. MATRIZ", "METROCAR S.A. 10 DE AGOSTO", "MOSUMI LA \"Y\"",
"distribuir contenidos", "proponer autoevaluaciones", "como buzón de actividades")
```

Option 1: Note that the accented "ó" is dropped in the last item.

```
gsub("[^[:ascii:]]|[[:punct:]]|[[:space:]]", "", Z, perl=TRUE)
# [1] "ANGLOAUTOMOTRIZSAMATRIZ"  "AUTOMOTORESYANEXOSAYASA"  "ECUAAUTOSAMATRIZ"        
# [4] "METROCARSA10DEAGOSTO"     "MOSUMILAY"                "distribuircontenidos"    
# [7] "proponerautoevaluaciones" "comobuzndeactividades"
```

Option 2: Note that the "ó" has been converted to "o"

```
gsub("[[:punct:]]|[[:space:]]", "", iconv(Z, to = "ASCII//TRANSLIT"))
# [1] "ANGLOAUTOMOTRIZSAMATRIZ"  "AUTOMOTORESYANEXOSAYASA"  "ECUAAUTOSAMATRIZ"        
# [4] "METROCARSA10DEAGOSTO"     "MOSUMILAY"                "distribuircontenidos"    
# [7] "proponerautoevaluaciones" "comobuzondeactividades"
```

Notes:

- For convenience, I've decided to just use the character classes `[[:punct:]]` and `[[:space:]]`.
- For the first option, you need `perl = TRUE` to recognize the `[[:ascii:]]` character class.
- The `^` in option 1 means "not" (so, you can read it as "find anything that is not an ASCII character, that is a space, or that is a punctuation mark, and replace it with nothing).

Comment: +1 for `iconv(Z, to = "ASCII//TRANSLIT")`, and thanks for adding this as an answer!